# How to measure a qubit Hamiltonian in qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit, measurement, vqe

I am using qiskit to get some measurement results of observables similar to the Hamiltonian. Can someone provide the way how qiskit measures the Hamiltonian (Jordan-Wigner transformed) when using VQE? Or can they just provide the source code link.

Answer (score 2):

Measurements in a VQE (also in Qiskit) are performed as projective measurements. Have a look [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/184524/what-is-the-difference-between-general-measurement-and-projective-measurement) for a related question in Physics SE.
Citing from Nielsen and Chuang's book "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information":

> A projective measurement is described by an observable, $M$, a Hermitian operator on the state space of the system being observed. The observable has a spectral decomposition, $$M = \sum_{m} mP_{m}$$ where $P_{m}$ is the projector onto the eigenspace of $M$ with eigenvalue $m$. The possible outcomes of the measurement correspond to the eigenvalues, $m$, of the observable. Upon measuring the state $|\psi\rangle$, the probability of getting result $m$ is $$p(m) = \langle\psi|P_{m}|\psi\rangle$$ Given that outcome $m$ occurred, the state of the quantum system immediately after the measurement is $$\frac{P_{m}|\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{p(m)}}$$

If you have access, also have a look at [this paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/18/2/023023/pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I believe these links can help solve your problem:
https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.aqua.algorithms.VQE.html
https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/qiskit.aqua.operators.expectations.html
https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/noise/1_hamiltonian_and_gate_characterization.html